# How many copies of V8 in NW.js and Electron?

Tags: electron, nw.js

Oversimplifying a bit, NW.js and Electron consist of parts of a browser (webkit, Chromium, or whatever) joined with a JavaScript engine (node.js,  io.js, or whatever).

My question is: How many copies of V8 are in there? I ask because I know that there is one in Chromium, and one in node.js.

Same question for NW.js.

I'm not asking how many are actually engaged in executing the app, but how many are present in the distributed app and, potentially, in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one copy of the V8 code, the node.js standard library is integrated into Chromium's V8 runloop. In memory, since Electron follows Chromium's multi-process model, each process will run a V8 runloop (i.e. the main process, plus one process per window).

Comment: Thanks -- exactly what I needed to know. I'm going to assume NW.js is similar, although I really only care about Electron.